# ¿Como validar un switch (materialize) con jquery?

Tags: html, jquery, materialize

En una tabla listo los usuarios traidos de una base de datos, y para validar que un usuario esta activo o inactivo uso un `SWITCHE (on/off)`...

```
  .done(function(rest) {
            let resp = $.parseJSON(rest);
            let output = '';
            resp.map((e, key) => {
                // Aqui valido si el usuario esta activo o inactivo
                resp[key]['estado'] != 0 ?  output = "<input type='checkbox' class='item' checked >" : output = "<input type='checkbox' class='item'>";

                    $('.tusers').append(`<tr>
                            <td>${resp[key]['codigocurso']}</td>
                            <td>${resp[key]['nombre']}</td>
                            <td>${resp[key]['email']}</td>
                            <td>${resp[key]['id']}</td>
                            <td>
                                <div class='switch' onclick='idUser(${resp[key]['id']})'>
                                    <label>
                                        Inactivo
                                        ${output}
                                        <span class='lever'></span>
                                        Activo
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td><button class='btn waves-light red'>Eliminar</button></td>
                        </tr>`);
            })
        })

function idUser(id){
        let checked;
        $(".item").change(function() {

            if($(this).is(":checked")) {
                checked = true;
            }
            else {
                checked = false;
           }

         $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/conexion/controllers/HomeClass.php/updatestate',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {'id': id, 'checked' : checked}
        })
        .done(function(resp) {          
            console.log(resp);
        })
        .fail(function() {
            console.log("error");
        });
        })

  }
```

**PROBLEMA**
Cuando voy actualizar el estado de un usuario con el switch, me cambia el estado de todos los usuario de diferentes maneras.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Se puede observar que al momento de cambiar un `switche`cambia el estado de los demas en el script, ¿como validar el cambio de un solo switch si afectar a los demas?**

Comment: Prueba  ponerles un id diferente a cada uno de los switchs

Comment: un atributo id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acá te dejo un ejemplo de como puedes hacer lo que estas tratando pero en vez de usar el evento onclick, puedes añadirle un atributo a cada checkboxs con su id, luego bindear el evento "change" a estos checkbox y obtener en la ejecucion del evento el id del checkbox y el status del mismo.

Espero que te sea de ayuda!

Saludos!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //Supongamos que a traves de tu ajax te llegan los siguientes datos
  let resp=[
      {
          codigocurso: 1,
          nombre: "pepe",
          email: "pepe@pepe.com",
          id: 1
      },
      {
          codigocurso: 2,
          nombre: "pepe2",
          email: "pepe2@pepe.com",
          id: 2
      }
  ];

  //cuando armas la tabla podes pasarle un "data-id" al checbox
  $.each(resp, function(index,value){
      $('.tusers').append(`<tr>
      <td>${value['codigocurso']}</td>
      <td>${value['nombre']}</td>
      <td>${value['email']}</td>
      <td>${value['id']}</td>
      <td>
          <div class="switch">
              <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" data-id="${value['id']}"> //<- aca el "data-id"
                  <span class="lever"></span>
              </label>
          </div>
      </td>
      <td><button class="btn waves-light red">Eliminar</button></td>
      </tr>`);
  });
  
  //luego bindeas el evento change a los checkbox, y obtenes el id del checkbox que se modifico en la ejecucion de cada evento
  $(".switch").find("input[type=checkbox]").on("change",function() {
      let checked = $(this).prop('checked');
      let id = $(this).data('id');
      console.log(id, checked);
      
      // de aca en adelante haces lo necesario con el codigo 
      /*
      $.ajax({
          url: 'http://localhost/conexion/controllers/HomeClass.php/updatestate',
          type: 'POST',
          data: {'id': id, 'checked' : checked}
      })
      .done(function(resp) {          
          console.log(resp);
      })
      .fail(function() {
          console.log("error");
      });
      */
      
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<table class="tusers">
</table>
```

Comment: Men es excelente, muchas gracias por tu colaboración....